# document.querySelector is undefined for standards mode iframe running in quirks mode parent

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10, quirks-mode, selectors-api

Experiencing this while running IE 10 with a bookmarklet. When I run the bookmarklet against a page running in quirks modes and I attempt to use document.querySelector, document.querySelector is undefined.

In an attempt to get around this, when I detect document.documentMode is 5 (quirks mode), I create an iframe and copy the content of the page into that iframe to put it in standards mode. I verify that the document in the iframe is in standards mode (document.documentMode is 8 - IE 8 standards mode) but document.querySelector is still undefined. I believe the documentMode has to be at least 9 for querySelector to be supported. I can't figure out why the documentMode is 8 instead of 10 since I'm running on IE 10.

```
if(goog.userAgent.IE && document.documentMode <= 5) {
    // strip out any scripts from the body
    s = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/<script\b[^<]*(?:(?!<\/script>)<[^<]*)*<\/script>/gi, '');

    frame = goog.dom.iframe.createBlank(goog.dom.getDomHelper());
    frame.scrolling = "no";
    frame.allowTransparency = true;
    frame.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.body.appendChild(frame);

    goog.dom.iframe.writeContent(frame, '<!doctype html>\n<html><head><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"></head><body>' + s + '</body></html>');

    doc = goog.dom.getFrameContentDocument(frame);
    alert(doc.documentMode); // 8 - IE 8 standards mode
    alert(doc.querySelectorAll); // null
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use feature detection for detecting `querySelectorAll()` rather than the documentMode number?

Comment: I used documentMode instead of simply checking (if(document.querySelector)) to help me debug this problem further

Answer (score 1):

> I used documentMode instead of simply checking (if(document.querySelector)) to help me debug this problem further